# JavaFX CodeArea in FXML (RichText)

Tags: java, javafx, richtext

I'm working on a Java project using [RichText](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX), and I have to implement a CodeArea to replace a TextArea. But since it's the very first time I'm using RichText, I have no idea how to declare my CodeArea directly in my FXML file.

I tried something like this :

```
<VirtualizedScrollPane>
      <content>
         <CodeArea fx:id="text"/>
     </content>
 </VirtualizedScrollPane>
```

But VirtualizedScrollPane doesn't have any constructor. I have this error :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualizedScrollPane.()

Sorry if my question is stupid. I literally have no idea of how and where I should declare the constructor.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What versions of the JDK and RichTextFX are you using (and how did you install RichTextFX)? RichTextFX has a dependency on [Flowless](https://github.com/FXMisc/Flowless) (which defines `VirtualizedScrollPane`): you need to make sure you have a recent enough version that annotates the constructor parameters with `NamedArg`, and a recent enough JDK that understands those (8u40 is enough).

Comment: Java version :

openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

I'v just downloaded the "fat" Jar provided in the documentation.

Comment: I think the bundled version of flowless in the fat jar is not recent enough to support FXML. Use Maven or Gradle to manage the dependency, and explicitly include version 0.6 or later of Flowless. (Or, somehow just make sure you are using 0.6 or later of Flowless...) For reference for the issue: https://github.com/FXMisc/Flowless/issues/25